# Получить callback от динамической клавиатуры в python telebot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

у меня есть список вроде такого `group_list = ['1 group', '6 group', '7 group', '8 group']`, его содержимое может меняться. Я пытаюсь сделать динамическую клавиатуру из этого списка, нашел на стаке пару вариантов, но никак не могу придумать как получить отклик от нажатия кнопки в боте?

Вот код:

```
def build_menu(buttons,n_cols,header_buttons=None,footer_buttons=None):
    menu = [buttons[i:i + n_cols] for i in range(0, len(buttons), n_cols)]
    if header_buttons:
        menu.insert(0, header_buttons)
    if footer_buttons:
        menu.append(footer_buttons)
    return menu

button_list = []
for each in group_list:
    button_list.append(types.InlineKeyboardButton(each, callback_data = each))
keyboard_group=types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(build_menu(button_list, n_cols=3)) #n_cols = 1 is for single column and mutliple rows
bot.send_message(call.chat.id, text='Choose group:', reply_markup=keyboard_group)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я решал эту проблему так:

1. Динамическое создание кнопок в цикле (это у вас есть)
2. Просто делаем `register_next_step_handler` после нажатия на кнопки

   ```
   # функция создания динамической клавиатуры
   def select(message):
     # Создаем клавиатуру
     buttons = ["1", "2", "3"]
     keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
       row_width=2, 
       resize_keyboard=True,                                                                
       one_time_keyboard=True
     )
     for button_content in buttons:
       btn =  types.KeyboardButton(button_content)
       keyboard.add(btn)
     # Отправляем клавиатуру
     msg = bot.send_message(
       chat_id, 'Выберите', 
       reply_markup=keyboard_consent_brand
     )
     bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, on_selection)
   # Функция обработки выбора из клавиатуры
   def on_selection(message):
     selection = message.text
     ### В selection теперь будет текст с кнопки, на которую нажали - то есть "1", "2" или "3", дальше можно работать с ним
   ```
3. Опицонально - удобно создавать словарик вида:

   ```
   button_actions = {"Текст на кнопке": func}
   ```

   Где `func` - функция, которую вы создали для действий по нажатию на кнопку, тогда в функции `selection` можно юзать `button_actions.keys()`, а в `on_selection` можно просто вызывать `button_actions[message.text]`.

Comment: Добрый день, спасибо, помогли.

Comment: Еще немного можете подсказать?

Comment: Да, спрашивайте

Comment: Может знаете как Pandas DF отправить одним сообщением в чатбот?

Comment: можно так https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html

Comment: Но я бы рекомендовал вам собственноручно разбирать Pandas DataFrame, чтобы показывать обработанную информацию

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать